# Problem importing pandas after succesfull installation on mac

Tags: pandas, pip

Although it seems that pandas is installed successfully on my mac

```
    >sudo -H pip install --user pandas
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Collecting pandas
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/52/ff/912fe03a623a70bcf297d466013a0b4f4c68c3b60f86bf226682d061fc09/pandas-0.24.2-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl (16.7MB)
     |################################| 16.7MB 1.7MB/s
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.5.0
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d4/70/d60450c3dd48ef87586924207ae8907090de0b306af2bce5d134d78615cb/python_dateutil-2.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (227kB)
     |################################| 235kB 1.4MB/s
Collecting numpy>=1.12.0
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/09/96/84cf406fe7d589f3dba9fc0f737e65985a3526c6d8c783f02d4b5a10825d/numpy-1.16.6-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (13.9MB)
     |################################| 13.9MB 1.7MB/s
Collecting pytz>=2011k
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e7/f9/f0b53f88060247251bf481fa6ea62cd0d25bf1b11a87888e53ce5b7c8ad2/pytz-2019.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (509kB)
     |################################| 512kB 1.4MB/s
Collecting six>=1.5
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/65/eb/1f97cb97bfc2390a276969c6fae16075da282f5058082d4cb10c6c5c1dba/six-1.14.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: six, python-dateutil, numpy, pytz, pandas
```

However, while trying to use it (python 2.7.17 )I do get an error

```
>>> import pandas as pd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pandas
>>>
```

any ideas ?

TIA

Comment: are you running the script in the same env that you installed pandas?

Comment: yes, once I am done installing pandas, I open a new tab and then trying to import pandas in python env

Comment: Instead of using stuff that's no longer supported (python 2.7), install [Anaconda Distribution with 3.7](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/).  It will leave your 2.7 env alone and you'll have all the stuff you need.  Incidentally, `import pandas as pd` & `import numpy as np` or people will be annoyed and look at you funny.

Comment: `sudo -H pip install --user` OMG Why?! You don't need both `sudo` and `--user` at the same time. One or the other; and mostly it's not `sudo`, it's a virtualenv or `--user`.

Comment: As for the import error: your `sudo -H pip` runs a different Python from what you use in console. So `pip` installed packages into one Python and you're trying to import them into another.